# ¿Como puedo mostrar 2 horas (Inicio-Fin) en un pdf en php?

Tags: php, pdf

tengo que mostrar en un pdf lo siguiente
Hora de inicio - Hora de fin en formato `HH:MM`
lo hace **n** veces, por ejemplo si se tiene 2 días, lunes y miércoles y el día lunes es un horario de 11:00 a 13:00 y el miércoles de 7:00 a 9:00, en el pdf lo debe mostrar así `11:00-13:00 / 7:00-9:00.`

```
for ($i=0; $i < $numgrupo; $i++) {
      $horaIni = $hora->horaIni;
      $horaFin = $hora->horaFin;
      $horaIni1[] = $hora->horaIni;
      $horaFin1[] = $hora->horaFin; 
      $horaIni = date_create($horaIni);
      $horaIni = date_format($horaIni,'H:i'); 
      $horaFin = date_create($horaFin);
      $horaFin = date_format($horaFin,'H:i');
      $horario = implode( " / ", $horaIni1).' - '. implode( " / ", $horaFin1);
}
```

y luego lo imprimo:

```
$pdf->Cell(62,5,$horario,0,1,'L',1);
```

pero el resultado en el pdf es el siguiente

```
11:00-7:00 / 13:00-9:00
```

¿qué puedo hacer para que muestre las horas (Ini y Fin) como lo mencioné anteriormente?

Comment: ¿Qué contiene ese objeto `$hora` del que extraes las propiedades `horaIni` y `horaFin`? Parece que es donde se te complica todo...

Comment: $arrGrupo = $objProfesor->($idGrupo);
    $numgrupo = count($arrGrupo);

    for ($i=0; $i < $numgrupo; $i++) { 

        $hora = (object)$arrGrupo[$i];
        $numdias = count($hora);

Comment: Hola @AdnamYam, modifica la pregunta e incluye ese código. En cualquier caso, no se ve el contenido de `$arrGrupo`. Revisa [ask] y bienvendo a [so]